# Pass a value from view.py to a url link in html

Tags: html, django, cs50

I am working on CS50 Web Development on the lesson of Django.

I want to pass a string from view.py to HTML as the URL link

here is the view.py

```
def randompage(request, name):
random_page = random.choice(util.list_entries())
return render(request, "encyclopedia/layout.html", {
"random_page": random_page})
```

and this is the HTML page

```
<a href="{% url 'randompage' random_page %}"> Random Page </a>
```

the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("wiki/<str:name>", views.title, name= "title"),
path("wiki/", views.randompage, name= "randompage"),
path("searchresult", views.searchresult, name= "searchresult"),
path("newpage", views.newpage, name= "newpage")
```

]

the error code is

> NoReverseMatch at /
> Reverse for 'randompage' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/$']

I know I shall you templatetag URL, but I don't really understand how it works and I cant find anyone have a similar situation with me.

Comment: please show your urls.py file code

Comment: updated

I'm working on the layout.html so it's not included in the urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the following in your HTML template:

```
<a href="{% url 'title' randompage %}"> Random Page </a>
```

- `title` is the path name from your urls.py
- `randompage` is the parameter

Here is the [relevant section of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: if the path i want to go is "wiki/<str:name>", shall I just write `<a href={% url 'wiki/' randompage %}> Random Page </a>`

Comment: @VicentLHKROT No, that won't work. The `{% url %}` tag needs a [URL Pattern Name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) as the first argument. `title` is the name you have given that URL pattern in your urls.py file.

Comment: @VicentLHKROT Just updated my answer. I had forgotten the quotation marks around the `url` tag.

Comment: this time i have subsituded it with `<a href="{% url 'title' randompage %}"> Random Page </a>`, but the error code `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'title' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P<name>[^/]+)$']` occurs. I should have returned a string for randompage

Comment: @VicentLHKROT If you are still having trouble, check the contents of `randompage` within your template.

Comment: let me check it first, coz it supposes to pass a string, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233730/discussion-between-vicent-lhk-rot-and-mattrowbum).